# What are the differences between Stack Overflow in Japanese and Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, languages, network-sites

When I searching on Google, I find the [Japanese Stack Overflow](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/) website.

But [the ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) exists over there.

What are the differences between the Japanese Stack Overflow and
Stack Overflow?

Does Japanese Stack Overflow translate from Stack Overflow? Or are they two separate websites?

Is the Japanese Stack Overflow website only for Japanese and Stack Overflow for all of the world?

Comment: How can you ask about the difference between 2 things and only link 1 of them? What exactly do you mean by "japan stackoverflows website"?

Comment: [A meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/383404/where-should-i-ask-my-question-related-to-english-grammar/383420#383420) that may or may not be causally (not a typo of *casually*) related.

Comment: Somewhat cryptic, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74243189/in-pysside2-how-can-i-show-the-thumbnail-for-an-item-in-qtextbrowser-when-the-u#comment131149066_74243189) could indicate [crossposting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossposting). It is normally frowned upon. Pick the language you are most comfortable with. And don't ever use machine translation (or the equivalent); it usually creates an incomprehensible mess.

Answer (score 8):

They're different sites.  They have a separate community, question base, answer base, etc.  There is no auto-translation between the two, either; one can use Stack Overflow without ever knowing about the existence of スタック・オーバーフロー, and vice-versa.

Comment: The only interaction between the sites would be community-curated links that point from the English site to a version of the question on one of the international sites, but only people with their browser chrome set to the supported language would see those. So if your browser menus were in Russian, and you landed on a question on the English site where a link had been established to a similar question on the Russian site, you'd see a special link to view it there.

Comment: I'm not sure if they're still automatically served, though.

Answer (score 7):

It is unclear which site you are asking about here, as all your links point to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), even where you talk about the Japanese site. There are 2 sites related to Japan in the Stack Exchange network, these are [スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/) (which according to Google translates to "Stack Overflow"), and [Japanese Language](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/).

[スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/) is a site *just like* [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). What subjects are on topic, what type of questions are on topic, etc, *should* all be more or less identical. There may be a little variation due to how the communities have evolved though, and [スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/) *may* be a little more permissive on the subjects as there aren't other sites in the community in Japanese that users would be able to visit in their native language (I do not speak Japanese so I *cannot* validate this).

There are other sites like [スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/) in the community as well, such as [Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/) (Russian), [Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/) (Portuguese), and [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) (Spanish). The content on these sites is *completely* separate from each other.

There is also another site in the community called [Japanese Language](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/); this is (as its name suggests) about the Japanese language. It has *no* overlap with [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). Questions on [Japanese Language](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/) are asked in English, but likely will include Japanese text, as they are asking how the language works, and often that will include written text.

If you are ever confused about what a site is about, you can always read their tour, which can always be found at {Site Domain}/tour. For the 3 sites I mention, that can be found at [Stack Overflow Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [スタック・オーバーフロー ツア](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tour), and [Japanese Language Tour](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/tour).